# AccessDeniedException when using Fine-Grained Access control for DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function behind API Gateway (Apollo Server to be precise) and I am accessing it via a react app by passing a JWT IdToken I am obtaining after logging in using Amplify Auth.

However when I attempt to run this application I continually get:

> AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::AWS Account ID:assumed-role/shop-app-xxx-XXX-CognitoAuthorizedRole-XXXXXXXXXX/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:AWS Account ID:table/Shop"

It is the following condition on my Role Policy which is causing this (see below for full role/policy).  I don't know enough to understand is there something wrong with my policy or is there something wrong with the way I'm obtaining my credentials. Does the `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` Action in my Role result in me no longer using the cognito identity to access the resource?

```
                Condition:
                    ForAllValues:StringEquals:
                            dynamodb:LeadingKeys:
                                - "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}
```

```
const identityToken = event.headers.Authorization;

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: `${process.env.IDENTITY_POOL_ID}`,
      Logins: {
        [`cognito-idp.${awsConfig.region}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.USER_POOL_ID}`]: identityToken
      }    
});

(AWS.config.credentials as AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials).refresh(function(err){
      if(!err) {
        console.log("no error");
        let dynamoDbClient:AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
        getShopModel(user,dynamoDbClient).shop().then((shop)=>{console.log(shop)});
      } else {
        console.log("got an error!");
        console.log(err);
      }
});
```

The following is my Authorized Role and the Mapping.  If I remove the LeadingKeys Condition from the inline Policy then everything works fine.  But of course I don't have fine grained control.

```
  CognitoAuthorizedRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              Federated: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
            Condition:
              StringEquals: 
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": !Ref ShopIdentityPool
              "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": authenticated
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "CognitoAuthorizedPolicy"
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "cognito-sync:*"
                  - "cognito-identity:*"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'dynamodb:GetItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:PutItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:Query'
                  - 'dynamodb:Scan'
                  - 'dynamodb:Delete*'
                  - 'dynamodb:Update*'
                Resource: [
                  !Sub "arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:*:table/${ShopTable}",
                  !Sub "arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:*:table/${ShopTable}/index/*"]
                Condition:
                    ForAllValues:StringEquals:
                            dynamodb:LeadingKeys:
                                - "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"

  ShopIdentityPoolRoleMapping:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment"
    Properties:
      IdentityPoolId: !Ref ShopIdentityPool
      Roles:
        authenticated: !GetAtt CognitoAuthorizedRole.Arn
        unauthenticated: !GetAtt CognitoUnAuthorizedRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems yaml and json are mixed in the Resource section.

Change the Resource section from

```
Resource: [
  !Sub "arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:*:table/${ShopTable}",
  !Sub "arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:*:table/${ShopTable}/index/*"]
```

to

```
Resource:
  - !Sub "arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:*:table/${ShopTable}",
  - !Sub "arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:*:table/${ShopTable}/index/*"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it @shimo. If changed it to the correct yaml structure but it seems cloudformation doesn't mind it either way.  Any other ideas?

Comment: `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` is for Identity ID. If you are using Identity Pool, please try `...:aud` instead.

Comment: thanks @shimo.  I'm wondering why I would need to use the :aud value instead?  Are you saying that because I have logged in using a federated identity the sub value isn't available? This seems odd.  I have created my records in dynamodb using sub as well.

Comment: Sorry if not work. I noticed id pool is used seeing your code, and found policy-condition with aud in [this aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/).